# Not getting result from ksql queries

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a kafka cluster running locally and a topic named "my-topic" in which im pushing data. I also have the ksql server running and the query: SELECT*FROM "my-topic" gives me "my-topic does not exist". I understand that this query is not right and i would like to know if there is another way to query a topic.

Comment: run `show tables`  in `Ksql` and check this table is exist?

Answer (score 3):

> the query: SELECT*FROM "my-topic" gives me "my-topic does not exist"

You can't do a SELECT directly against a Kafka topic in KSQL -- the only two statements in KSQL that allow you to work directly against topics are (1) `PRINT <topic_name>` and (2) `SHOW TOPICS`.

Instead, you need to [create streams](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/syntax-reference.html#create-stream) (`CREATE STREAM`) and/or [create tables](https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/syntax-reference.html#create-table) (`CREATE TABLE`) in KSQL, whose input data will be read and parsed from the desired Kafka topic. Think of streams and tables in KSQL as "Kafka topics with a schema" (see my recent write-up [Of Streams and Tables in Kafka and Stream Processing, Part 1](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2018/04/05/of-stream-and-tables-in-kafka-and-stream-processing-part1/) for more information).

Example:

```
CREATE STREAM pageviews (viewtime BIGINT, userid VARCHAR, ...)
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='pageviews-topic', \
      VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED');
```